# New float environment in beamer

Tags: beamer

I writing a presentation and I need a new float type made "Quadro". I am using beamer. Brazilian stylesheet demands all tables (for quantitative data) and "Quadros" (a table with text and qualitative data) to be named as: table 1: XXXXXX.

I tried a number of possibilites, but none with any results. here some of my tentatives. As I try in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{quadro}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{quadro}{Quadro}
```

and write in the document:

```
\begin{block}{O livro e seu protagonismo}
O livro tem se caracterizado como principal recurso há 400 anos
\end{block}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{quadro}    
\begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|c||c|}
    \hline 
    Reutilizar & Revisar \\ 
    Sim & Não \\ 
    \hline 
        \hline 
    Recombinar & Redistribuir \\ 
    Não & Depende \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}
\caption{Status do livro didático enquanto recurso}
\end{quadro}
\end{frame}
```

But I get the following errors messages:

```
Not in outer par mode. \end{frame}
Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{frame}
Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{frame}
Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{frame}
```

thanks

Comment: What should your new environment do? Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: floats in a presentation make no sense!

Comment: Which error exactly, one about "not in outer par mode"? If so, try `\begin{quadro}[H]`.  `beamer` is for presentations, and floats doesn't really make sense there, `[H]` turns off floating.

Comment: The Brazilian stylesheet (ABNT) demands all tables, pictures etc to numbered and named even on presentations. So it makes total sense in some point of view

Comment: Thank you for adding context of why you “need” a float. However, I agree with @Herbert’s comment that you don’t actually *need* a float. If you are required to provide numbers for tables and figures, then I’d suggest `\captionof` from the `caption` package. So you can use `\captionof{quadro}{Status...}` without `\begin{quadro}...\end{quadro}` instead of `\caption{Status...}`.

Comment: ABNT has **absolutely** no rules for presentations. You should know that.

Comment: It seems package float not works with beamer presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter)  said in her comment, define new float which replace standard `table` and use it as standard table, has no sense. i would write your table code example with simpler (and shorter) standard way:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames,table}]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]% for numbered figures and tables captions

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{use of tables \dots}
\begin{block}{O livro e seu protagonismo}
O livro tem se caracterizado como principal recurso há 400 anos
\end{block}

\begin{table}
\rowcolors{1}{LightGray}{}
\centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    Reutilizar & Revisar \\
    Sim & Não \\
    \hline
    \hline
    Recombinar & Redistribuir \\
    Não & Depende \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Status do livro didático enquanto recurso}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]